# How do I attach detached objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

The title already says it ... I'm looking for a way to attach my detached objects.

http://jsfiddle.net/jy2Zj/

At the moment I can realize an alert only. How would I replace the function?

Thanks for your help.

***Edit***
Another question came up to my mind. Is there a way to suppress the closing of the select box after choosing "all"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if i understood what you meant..
If i am right you want to simply make a list of all detached objects so you can add them again later:

```
myArr = ['v2', 'v11'];

var detached = [];

$('select[name="test"] option').each(function() {
   if ($.inArray(this.value, myArr) !== -1) {
      detached.push($(this).detach());
   }
});

$.each(detached,function() {
      $('select[name="test"]').find('option').end().append(this);
});

$('select[name="test"]').find('option').end().append('<option value="all">All</option>');
```